# Certification and Key Management Expiration

Tags: sandbox, certificates, api-client-certificate, identity-provider

I have been researching about certification renewal and expiration and am confused if I need to renew or not. I read [here](https://saas-components.com/sfdc-expiring-certificate/) that I only need a certificate if I have "service providers" in my org.

I can see that one of my certifications is going to expire in the next ten days but I do not have any service providers; so am I to assume I do not need this (soon to be expired SelfSignedCert) certificate at all? Why would we have it in the first place if it does not need to be renewed?

And as a follow up, if I do need to renew it, is [this answer](https://saas-components.com/sfdc-expiring-certificate/) the best path to renewing?

Comment: Do you use Single Sign-On (SSO) in your Org?

Comment: @AayushK none of the active users in the org are set up for SSO

Comment: If SSO was setup on your org at some point, then that may explain why you have a SelfSigned Certificate. If no one is using SSO, then I don't think you should have any issues if the certificate expires. You can check under the Single Sign On settings to see if settings for SSO exist and if it is pointing to this certificate.